# Apache remove pattern from Request URI

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have url like this :

```
wwww.example.com/web/foo/page1  
wwww.example.com/web/foo/page2  
wwww.example.com/web/foo/page1?q=helloworld
```

I need clean url like.

```
wwww.example.com/page1  
wwww.example.com/page2  
wwww.example.com/page1?q=helloworld
```

Need to remove **web/foo** from the URL for all the urls.

I tied following but not have any positive results

```
RewriteRule ^/web/foo/(.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Can any one suggest me to correct rule.??

Comment: something like this maybe? `RewriteRule ^web/foo/(.*?)$ http://wwww.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]`

Comment: You want external redirect? So that the browser will display the changed URL? Or internal redirect (browser will still see original url `/web/foo/page1`)?

Comment: Not working.. :-( it redirects me to www.example.com

Comment: @Marki555 "external redirect", this is what i need.

Comment: Where is this .htaccess located? Are there existing rules?

Comment: We created separate virtual host in "example.conf" site. only other existing rule is for proxypass for ajp.